# setError method in android returning to parent activity

Tags: android

I have a editText field in my activity CreateTripActivity and it is having one parent activity.

I want to display a error message when I click on save button without entering any value on editText field.

I have done this using editTextField.setError("Error Message");

But it is returning to the parent activity just after showing the error message, I do not want to show the parent activity, I need to be on the same CreateTripActivity when any error message is shown here.

Can you please help me so that I can show the error message on the same form without returning to the parentActivity...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: please share your code

Comment: take a look @ http://www.dmytrodanylyk.com/pages/blog/error-label.html

Comment: I have figured out the solution for this... Thanks for your time here... :)

Comment: But I am having one issue with setError method, after adding the error message to any field, the error message is not cleared when I start typing in the field, I want the error message to be disappear. Can you please help me here to figure it out.

Comment: Have a look at android TextWatcher and text.setError(null)

Comment: Thank you so much for this information, it worked...  Well I want to know how to make a editText field as autocomplete of Google Places in android... Can you please help me here...

Comment: I want to reload a fragment. I am having an activity and two fragments in it. Fragments having a button and on clicking on this button we call another activity to display a form. This activity is having one button and on clicking on this button I need to go back to the fragment from where I have come to this activity. Can you please help me here....